# Java wildcards and generic methods

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a class using a Map as field variable:

```
private Map<String, ?> posts;
```

And in that same class I have a generic method:

```
public <T> void log(T message) {
   if (isEnabled) {
        Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS");
        posts.put(sdf.format(time.getTime()), message);
    }
}
```

However I get a compiler error on the posts.put statement saying:

```
The method put(String, capture#2-of ?) in the type Map<String,capture#2-of ?> is not 
applicable for the arguments (String, T)
```

I'm a bit new to wildcards and generic methods so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: posts should be `private Map<String, T> posts;` as you know, that it contains T elements.

Comment: Just for consideration, don't ever use time as a key. Time has a limited resolution and is therefore not a key. Everytime you put something into the map at the same millisecond, your old value will be overwritten. Use a counter instead.

Answer (score 4):

`Map<String, ?>` doesn't mean you can put *anything* into that map. It means the value class is *unknown*. But it can be e.g. Foo or Bar. And Foo might be incompatible with any type `T`, so the compiler complains. Use `Map<String, Object>` instead or make your `T` parameter class-level and then parametrize your map with it: `Map<String, T>`

Answer (score 4):

When you declare your `Map` with an unbounded wildcard type:

```
private Map<String, ?> posts;
```

you won't be able to put anything apart from `null` into it. Because `?` is a substitute for any type. Basically, your `Map` is a supertype of all the instantiation of `Map` with `String` as a key, and value of any type. `?` can be *Date*, *Number*, *Cat*, *Tiger*, anything.

Suppose your map is instantiated like this:

```
private Map<String, ?> posts = new HashMap<String, Date>();
```

and the type parameter in your method is inferred as `String`, then your `put` method is doing:

```
posts.put(String, String);
```

...thus trying to add `String` type where a `Date` is needed. Certainly that would fail at runtime. Generic type avoids these issue by issuing a compiler error for this.

---

You can solve this problem by making your class itself generic, thus using the same type parameter in the method and map:

```
class YourClass<T> {
    private Map<String, T> posts;

    public void log(T message) {
        if (isEnabled) {
            Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS");
            posts.put(sdf.format(time.getTime()), message);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also as noted in comments, you should avoid having `time` as key. Since `Date#getTime()` has only milliseconds precision, so anything you put during the interval that is covered in a single milliseconds, will be stored as the same key, thus overwriting the old value for that key.